# Зачем используется слово «некоторый» в качестве определения, если оно не определяет никакой признак или свойство?

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис, грамматика, значение-слов, местоимения

> **НЕ́КОТОРЫЙ**, -ая, -ое, мест. неопределенное.
>
> 1. Какой-то, точно не определенный. *Писарь настолько потерялся, что некоторое время не мог выговорить ни одного слова.* Мамин-Сибиряк,
>    Хлеб. *Оба молчали и чувствовали некоторую неловкость.* Чехов, Степь.
>    [Словарь русского языка Евгеньевой]

*Сразу оговорюсь, что меня интересует именно это значение слова «некоторый», а не другие его значения.*

---

Рассмотрим пример из словаря:

*Оба молчали и чувствовали **некоторую** неловкость.*
Чехов, Степь.

«…чувствовали *какую неловкость?* некоторую…» — «некоторую» здесь определение.

> **Определе́ние** — второстепенный член предложения, обозначающий признак,
> качество, свойство предмета. Отвечает на вопросы: *какой? который? чей?*
> [[Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81))].

«Некоторую неловкость», исходя из значения слова «некоторый» в словаре, означает: *какую-то, точно не определённую неловкость.*

Какой же признак или свойство объекта «неловкость» обозначает определение «некоторую»? Никакой.
Может, оно даёт информацию о грамматических категориях слова «неловкость»? Тоже вроде бы нет.

Но зачем тогда вообще использовать это слово, если оно по сути не определяет никаких признаков объекта и никакой новой информации не сообщает?

*«Оба молчали и чувствовали неловкость»* — ведь смысл вообще не изменился без «некоторую».

---

*Таким образом, я имею **некоторое** время для того, чтобы вспомнить, прежде чем погибнуть, о своих открытиях.*
Иван Ефремов, Сердце змеи (сборник).

«Некоторое время» — какое-то, точно не определённое время.

Если убрать:
*«Таким образом, я **имею время** для того, чтобы вспомнить, прежде чем погибнуть, о своих открытиях»* — смысл не поменялся.

---

*Правда, тело не может привести себя целиком в движение одними лишь внутренними силами, но оно может заставить **некоторую** часть своей массы двигаться в одну сторону, остальную же — в другую, противоположную.*
Яков Перельман, Занимательная физика. Книга 2, 1916

Без «некоторую»:
*Правда, тело не может привести себя целиком в движение одними лишь внутренними силами, но оно может **заставить часть** своей массы двигаться в одну сторону, остальную же — в другую, противоположную.*

---

Так зачем же всё-таки использовать слово в качестве определения, если оно никаких признаков объекта не определяет и на никакие грамматические категории слова, обозначающего объект, не указывает?

«Некоторый» — это неопределённое местоимение.

> **Неопределённые местоиме́ния (лат. pronomen indefinitum, англ.
> indefinite pronouns)** — местоимения, указывающие на то, что референт
> (объект, к которому отсылает местоимение) или его свойства (признак,
> количество и т. п.) неизвестны или неточно известны участникам речевой
> ситуации, то есть являются неопределёнными. Кроме того, неопределённое
> местоимение способно выражать дополнительную информацию о референте:
> пол, число, одушевлённость и т. д. [[Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)]

Однако несмотря на то, что местоимения называются неопределёнными, они часто имеют лексическое значение и выполняют нужную синтаксическую функцию — без них нельзя или трудно обойтись.

*В комнате явно **кто-то** был.* [пример из [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)]

> **КТО́-ТО**, кого́-то и т. д. (см. кто), мест. неопределенное.
>
> 1. Неизвестно какой человек; некто. *[Моцарт:] Сказали мне, что заходил За мною кто-то.* Пушкин, Моцарт и Сальери. *Вдруг позади нас в овраге
>    раздался шум: кто-то спускался к источнику. Я оглянулся и увидал
>    мужика лет пятидесяти.* Тургенев, Малиновая вода…

В предложении *«В комнате явно **кто-то** был»* местоимение «кто-то» выполняет функцию подлежащего, о котором неизвестно говорящему. Таким образом, оно имеет как семантическое значение (сообщает, что тот, о ком говорится, неизвестен говорящему), так и синтаксическую функцию (выполнят роль подлежащего). Его нельзя просто так убрать:
*«В комнате явно был»* — мысль получается незаконченной.

---

- Какое же значение и/или функция в предложении у слова «некоторый»
  в примерах, приведённых мной вначале?
- Для чего оно используется
  авторами, если его наличие или отсутствие ничего не меняет?

Comment: @Александр Стрелец Спасибо за исправление ошибок!

Answer (score 2):

> - Оба молчали и чувствовали **некоторую** неловкость.
> - Таким образом, я имею **некоторое** время для того, чтобы вспомнить, прежде чем погибнуть, о своих открытиях.

В этих примерах, на мой взгляд, слово *некоторую* используется как синоним слов *небольшую/ое*, а не для обозначения неопределенности.

> Правда, тело не может привести себя **целиком** в движение одними лишь внутренними силами, но оно может заставить **некоторую** часть своей массы двигаться в одну сторону, остальную же — в другую, противоположную.

А здесь, на мой взгляд, оно добавлено для симметрии со словом *целиком*.

Слово же *целиком* используется с той целью, чтобы **заранее** дать читателю понять (= подготовить его к тому, что...), что физическое тело (а точнее его масса) будет рассматриваться в качестве **нескольких** частей, а не в качестве единого целого.

Заметьте, кстати, использование слова *нескольких*, которое является необязательным ровно по той же причине.

Comment: Разумная мысль. Я поставил вам плюсик, надо подумать над этим.

Comment: Дело в том, что такое значение есть в том же словаре: **2. Кое-какой, незначительный.** *— А вы были в Москве, доктор? — Да, я имел там **некоторую** практику.* Лермонтов, Княжна Мери. *— Имеете вы хотя бы **некоторое** состояние? --- — Никакого состояния покамест я не имею.* Достоевский, Идиот.

Comment: Однако пример: *Оба молчали и чувствовали некоторую неловкость. Чехов, Степь* – из первого значения. Но может составители словаря ошибочно туда его поставили или что-то вроде опечатки. Надо посмотреть другие словари. В другом примере из определения с неопределённостью без этого слова не обойтись: *Писарь настолько потерялся, что **некоторое время** не мог выговорить ни одного слова.* Мамин-Сибиряк, Хлеб.  Нельзя почему-то сказать просто: *«Писарь настолько потерялся, **что время** не мог выговорить ни одного слова».* Возможно, это слово нужно потому, что время неисчисляемое существительное.

Comment: Я ваш ответ пока не принимаю (но плюсик поставил), хочу ещё подумать, и, может, кто-то ещё что-то скажет. Большое спасибо, что ответили. Приятно читать человека, который логически мыслит и ясно излагает.

Comment: @Eagle Если подумать, то в примере со _Степью_, слово _некоторую_ может использоваться и в значении неопределенности тоже. Например - я не читал произведение - неловкость может быть вызвана дружескими чувствами; либо тем, что один персонаж помог другому, а тот  не имел возможности отблагодарить, и первый персонаж тоже это знал; либо разным социальным статусом. Эти примеры немного кривые (4:18 утра), но думаю мысль понятна. Автор дает нам намёк, что эта неловкость была **одной из**, но уточнять какой именно - считает лишним.